# Add chrome to devices in android studio

Tags: google-chrome, android-studio, dart

since flutter 1.9 flutter web adds chrome as a device. (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)

How can I add chrome as device to android-studio in order to run my code from android-studio instead of the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think they have updated android-studio, because it's selectable now.